# Searching string from text file

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to search a certain string from an input file. Firstly, the code stores data from input file and then it searches the user input data in the text file, but when i try to print one of the variables it ends up being null.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
        BufferedReader input = null;
        PrintWriter output = null;
        try {
            input = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("kolej.txt"));
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            in.useDelimiter("\n");
            int index = 0;

            String indata = null;
            System.out.println("UITM College and Non-Residents Registration System");
            System.out.println("Enter your student id: ");
            String matrix = in.next();

            UITM student[] = new UITM[10];

            //storing data into array
            while ((indata = input.readLine())!= null) {

                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(indata,";");
                student[index] = new Kolej(st.nextToken(), st.nextToken(), st.nextToken(), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), st.nextToken(),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), st.nextToken(),Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken())) ;
                index++;
            } 
            //searching
            Scanner txtscan = new Scanner(new File("kolej.txt"));
            while(txtscan.hasNextLine()) {
                matrix = txtscan.nextLine();
                if(matrix.indexOf("word") != -1) {
                    System.out.println(student[0].getName());
                }
            }
            input.close();
            output.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please tell  more -- which variable is null? What line of code is the one involved?

Comment: basically im clueless i just need to know if im storing and searching the data correctly